# UIStackView race condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistackview

I have a nested UIStackView which when I press a button it's instantiated. To go into more detail I have a UIStackView that iterates through a NSMutableArrayList full of CustomUIStackViews and adds them as arrangedSubviews. When the CustomUIStackViews initiate they also iterate through their own NSMutableArrayList filled with UIViews and adds them as arrangedSubviews.

The strange thing is that after all of my for loops are executed I have an NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"parentstackview height is %f",_parentStackView.frame.size.height);
```

which returns a 0 (which it shouldn't, the height should be 1861 after all the stackviews show up, which they visibly do in the simulator).

But if I create this method:

```
- (void)testMethod{
    NSLog(@"parentstackview height is %f",_parentStackView.frame.size.height);
}
```

and replace the NSLog from before with this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(testMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Then it returns 1861 exactly like it should, after the 1 second delay.

Why does the 1 second delay make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A layout pass likely wasn't done within your code, but handled later in the run loop, which accounts for the differing values.

If you require the size in the same code that instantiates the nested stack views, you'd need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` to immediately layout all the subviews.

You wouldn't have found those details in the `UIStackView` documentation, as it is documented in the stack view's superclass [UIView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW58) under Laying Out Subviews.